# Android Studio: listview shows nothing for Wifi p2p

Tags: java, android, listview, wifip2p

I'm writing code for discovering Wifi and showing the list. If wifi can't be detected, toasts "No Device". However, both list and toast are not showing up. Anything wrong with it?

My code is:

```
public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peerList) {
        if (!peerList.getDeviceList().equals(peers)){
          peers.clear();
          peers.addAll(peerList.getDeviceList());

          deviceNameArray=new String[peerList.getDeviceList().size()];
          deviceArray=new WifiP2pDevice[peerList.getDeviceList().size()];

          int index = 0;

          for(WifiP2pDevice device : peerList.getDeviceList()){
                deviceNameArray[index] = device.deviceName;
                deviceArray[index] = device;
                index++;
          }

          ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,deviceNameArray);
          listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        if (peers.size()==0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `getApplicationContext()` for the `ArrayAdapter` instantiation. Use the current `Activity`; e.g., `this`, or `YourActivity.this`. Possibly the text is blending in with the background, because the application `Context` won't have the right theme on it. If that doesn't fix it, debug to check the size of the resulting arrays. Also, make sure that the `ListView` is actually visible on-screen.

Comment: What is peers.size() when it gets to the final if statement?

Comment: I modified the code for showing peer.size(), but still nothing. Also, MyActivity.this doesn't work.

Comment: "I modified the code for showing peer.size(), but still nothing." – What do you mean by that, exactly? Are you saying that it's supposed to `Toast` that size every time now, but it doesn't? Are you sure that code is running at all? If so, what is the value of `peers.size()`? Also, what is the `length` of `deviceNameArray` right after the `for` loop? Are you sure that you can see that `ListView` on-screen?

Comment: Problem solved by replacing getApplicationContext() with "this" on Android 10 API 29.Thank you !